# Executeupdate() taking long time also stop the process

Tags: java, sql

I have a submit button and when I click on that button , in background update query will execute but executeupdate() statement take so much time and system gets hang and it's not giving any error or exception. and whole process gets stop.
below i am mentioning the code for updation :

```
String sql1 = "Update M_Locator set IS_EMPTY = ? where m_locator_id = "+M_Locator_ID;
                pstmt1 = DB.prepareStatement(sql1, null);
                if(p_LocatorUtilized.doubleValue() == 0) 
                    {
                        pstmt1.setString(1, "Y");
                    }
                else
                    {
                        pstmt1.setString(1, "N");
                    }


                pstmt1.executeUpdate();

                DB.close(pstmt1);
```

How can I check  this please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should try to increase query timeout on your database connection.

Second thing, more important is about your database itself. Try to set index on both fields to avoid full table scan and speed up this update query.

Comment: How can i increase query time out in database connection

Comment: it depends: what is your database and what library is used to connect to it.